# Rspec creating users in rails and filling database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have rspec tests in my rails app that run some methods, mainly:

methods_helper.rb

```
  def registered_admin
    @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in "user_username", with: @admin.username
    fill_in "user_password", with: @admin.password

    click_button 'Sign in'
  end
```

factories.rb

```
factory :admin, class: User do
    username "adminuser"
    email "admin@example.com"
    password "admin246"
    admin true
end
```

and other assortment of capybara things like filling in lesson forms and checking validations/count etc.

However I noticed running my tests that it creates space in the actual User database, I have 1 main user, id: 1. I created a second one and its suddenly id: 34. Running rspec spec/ and in sandbox I created another, id: 36.

Everything from 2 through 33 is nil. What part of my tests are permanently affecting the DB? I kind of thought tests ran in their own section and didnt "actually" touch the database but just simulate it. Am I wrong? What part of my tests can be changed so it doesn't keep extending the total id's?

(another model is run in the same way, it does not have the same problem, only user id's are actual created entries)

Also, is there any command/way to "free up" the 30 or so nil user.ids?

Comment: IDs are only guaranteed to be unique, not consecutive, or even in order. You should not rely on them being in sequence - the only thing they are to be used for are retrieving rows from database.

Comment: The only real issue is that it's irritating, I hadn't relied on sequence or anything. Eitherway, is this not an issue that shouldn't be occurring?

Comment: In the database.yml file did you specify different databases. As you said they are going in the main database. And as the test database is created and deleted so your ids between 2 to 33 are nil. As they have been used already and cannot be reused until the table is truncated. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Deep
database.yml specify's different db's (site_development & site_test). Also I have tests running similar methods on a Lesson model and this does not have the same issue. Thanks for letting me know about truncate. I guess next step is to run test by test and find the actual method that's doing it, then find out what to change?

Comment: Yes that's the best way I guess.

Comment: I got up this morning and went back to working on this issue, and it's gone. Tests don't make any entries in dev database anymore. Which is great and all... but I wonder what happened? Very curious. Thanks for your suggestions.